# populating list and objects from JSON

Tags: c#, json, list, object

I'm new to both StackOverflow and C#. I have made a JSON file for my WinForm application to store all of the settings about it and I need to read from the file in order to populate a dynamic List of objects (and them too).

I am using the newtonsoft Json.net library but, not having both experience in programming and a good knowledge of the OOP, I don't know what to do and whether what I'm doing is correct. So I have to read the file, look for a specific value, populate the list, then create an instance of the value's objects and populate them with their properties.

```
    public class myList
    {
        public string listName { get; set; }
        public MyList()
        {

        }

        public void popList()
        {
            string filePath = Settings.Instance.getFilePathName();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr);
            List<MyList> list = new List<MyList>();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    list = data["value"].ToObject<List<MyList>>();
                }
            }
   public class Value {
       public string name1 {get;set;}
       public string name2 {get;set;}
       public Value() {

       }
   }
```

And this for the objects as well.

The JSON file is looking like this:

```
{
    "myList" : [
        "value1" : {
            "subvalue1" : ".....",
            "subvalue2" : "....."
        },
        "value2" : {
            "subvalue1" : ".....",
            "subvalue2" : "....."
        }
    ]
}
```

etc...

Comment: Use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)

This will return a dynamic object with the properties. Make sure you do error checks before accessing properties or it will result in a runtime exception

Comment: Your json isn't currently valid - it appears myList should be an array of objects, so you need [ { "value1"  etc...  - Not [ "value1"

Comment: I fixed the json file but I can't still access the values from the program itself.